# Windows 10 - Is there a persistent product id through the updates?

Tags: windows-10, uuid

I am wondering if there is a persistent ID value through the Windows updates.

To put it in context, I have a licensing system that ties the license to the machine's Product ID, but it changes with every update of the OS.

Is there some ID value that stays the same after every update?

Comment: Is there a development question tied to this ? You should try to avoid having an external license dependency for your own licensing.. What are you doing as there might be a better way.

Comment: @Pogrindis, what do you mean to avoid external license dependency? 
What I do is, send the user a license key, that the user uses it to "unlock" the software. I use the Product ID to tie the license key to that particular machine.

Comment: You can use [HardwareIdentification.GetPackageSpecificToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.profile.hardwareidentification.getpackagespecifictoken.aspx) to get a hardware thumbprint which is not affected by OS reinstalls or updates. [This web page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj553431.aspx) explains how it works, so you can have your own logic to decide how many hardware changes are too many.

Comment: @RaymondChen thank you, it seems that should do.